# Laravel 5: find the page number of an entry

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm working on a custom forum and when a post is added to a thread I have to notify the subscribed users. In the message I have to place the link for the user to go straight to the post. Something like this:

```
/forum/discussion/1/ateliers-et-expositions?page=2#forum-message-3
```

To be able to do that I need to know the page number of the entry. Does this feature exist on Laravel already? I couldn't find it in their docs and I know about features that exist but are not in their docs, so maybe it's there already and I'm just not aware of it.

I would like to avoid making a select in the database a loop through it to find the page number, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely look for `get()` method of `Request` class. Assuming you want to get this in your controller method, say `foo()`, you should have:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function foo(Request $request)
{
    $page = $request->get('page');
    ...
```